# Expected? CDI Request scoped bean injected into producer injected into dependent bean gives WELD-001303: No active contexts

Tags: java, cdi, weld, cdi-unit

Assume that the RequestScope is active (Using cdi-unit's @InRequestScope)

Given

```java
package at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi;

public class Product {

    public Product(String withValue){
        this.value = withValue;
    }

    public String value;

}
```

- an injection of Product into that active request scope

```java
package at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi;
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.jglue.cdiunit.AdditionalClasses;
import org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner;
import org.jglue.cdiunit.InRequestScope;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(CdiRunner.class)
@AdditionalClasses({ Producer.class, SomeCache.class })
public class ExpectedTest {

    @Inject
    Product productA;

    @Inject
    Product productB;

    @Test
    @InRequestScope
    public void testScoping() {
        Assert.assertNotNull(productA);
        System.out.println(productA.value);
        Assert.assertNotNull(productB);
    }

}
```

- using a dependent Producer (with InjectionPoint Parameter, so must be dependent)

```java
package at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi;

import javax.enterprise.inject.Produces;
import javax.enterprise.inject.spi.InjectionPoint;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class Producer {

    public static final String VALUE_B = "valueB";

    public static final String VALUE_A = "valueA";

    @Inject
    SomeCache someCache;

    @Produces
    public Product produceProduct(InjectionPoint ip) {
        if (!VALUE_B.equals(someCache.getCacheValue())) {
            someCache.setCacheValue(VALUE_A);
        } else {
            someCache.setCacheValue(VALUE_B);
        }
        return new Product(someCache.getCacheValue());
    }

}
```

- and that producer should be injected a request scoped bean

```java
package at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi;

import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;

@RequestScoped
public class SomeCache {

    private String cacheValue;

    public String getCacheValue() {
        return cacheValue;
    }

    public void setCacheValue(String cacheValue) {
        this.cacheValue = cacheValue;
    }

}
```

When this fails cause of the request scoped bean with

```java
org.jboss.weld.context.ContextNotActiveException: WELD-001303: No active contexts for scope type javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getContext(BeanManagerImpl.java:708)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$CachingContextualInstanceStrategy.getIfExists(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.getIfExists(ContextualInstance.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:83)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi.SomeCache$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getCacheValue(Unknown Source)
    at at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi.Producer.produceProduct(Producer.java:18)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:88)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.StaticMethodInjectionPoint.invoke(StaticMethodInjectionPoint.java:78)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethodProducer.java:95)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.AbstractMemberProducer.produce(AbstractMemberProducer.java:167)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:183)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:761)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getInjectableReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:861)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:92)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:375)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:386)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector$1.proceed(ResourceInjector.java:70)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.ResourceInjector.inject(ResourceInjector.java:72)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.producer.BasicInjectionTarget.inject(BasicInjectionTarget.java:121)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:159)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:96)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:101)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$ApplicationScopedContextualInstanceStrategy.get(ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:141)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(ContextualInstance.java:50)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:99)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.getInstance(ProxyMethodHandler.java:125)
    at at.joma.stackoverflow.cdi.ExpectedTest$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.testScoping(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.jglue.cdiunit.CdiRunner$2.evaluate(CdiRunner.java:179)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

- Is this the per CDI expected behavior?
- If yes, because of the dependent pseudo scope of Producer?
- Why does this not fail if SomeCache is application scoped instead of request scoped?

What is a reasonable scope solution for SomeCache?

That (not-working) request scoped SomeCache does cache some data that the producer needs to produce the first to-be-injected bean. So it can

- neither be dependent (as this renders caching useless)
- nor should it be application scoped or static (too broad a scope)

Ideally it should automagically be in the same scope of the bean where  Product is injected - in the example that is ExpectedTest. May well be another custom cdi scope, but should not depend on the client/user developer defining that scope.  One may call that a "transitive scope-dependent bean", if that makes any sense.

Comment: Question's very hard to follow, I'm sorry.  Can you share some of your code and the full stacktrace?

Comment: Hi @JohnAment, thanks for commenting. Added code, trace and aligned text with classes.

Answer (score 2):

Is this the per CDI expected behavior? -> No

Cause of the failure was that cdi-unit does not log/report that it could not setup the request scope. And therefore i missed to define the following dependency. BTW that one is defined as provided in cdi-unit. So it is all about scopes :)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```